# RabbitMQ Disaster Recovery

Tags: rabbitmq

In our primary site, we have 2 instances of RabbitMQ (with clustering and HA enabled) running in Active-Active mode. Both of these instances also run Apache Camel which acts as consumers. In our DR site, there would initially be one RabbitMQ instance and another instance can subsequently be added.

How can we perform DR from primary site to DR site?

Challenges I foresee are that RabbitMQ queues were written to 2 data stores in primary site but need to be combined in one node in DR site initially and then again divided into 2 nodes (once another instance in DR comes up).

Comment: did you get any chance to achieve this behaviour? Can you please share if you have manage to setup this DR.